# Could a bot imitate random human behaviour when clicking on an image?

Tags: php, image, security, captcha, bots

Please tell me, could such a Captcha alternative work?

Basically if I use something like this:

```
<?php
$foo_x=$_POST['foo_x'];
$foo_y=$_POST['foo_y']
?>

<form action="http://foo.com/function/" method="post">
<input type="image" alt="image" src="img.jpg" name="foo"/>
</form>
```

And so a real user would click at a random X,Y coordinates, which I can then pass to "function" which in turn will send the user to the content, unless it's a bot.

The question is whether a bot that would go to the link specified in `action=`, would do so via the image - "clicking" on it, and if so then would the bot get a random coordinate or just "click" the exact center or the 0,0 coordinate? Or would it just go to the link directly without triggering `$_POST` at all? Could a bot be programmed to "click" a random spot on such an image?

Do you know of a better way of achieving such anti-bot image functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: The only way to get the coordinates with this method would be with javascript. It wouldn't take much for someone to write a bot to bypass this.

Comment: It's an easy thing to fake $_POST data. A bot will not "click" on the image, just send a $_POST['foo_x'] and a $_POST['foo_y'] value

Comment: @Ian input type="image" sends the x and y coördinates in the $_POST, so why Javascript?

Comment: Indeed why JS, Ian? ôkio, So how could you protect POST data from being faked then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hate Captchas, you could write easily a function that can somehow guess if it is a human or a bot ie

1. Time difference between page load and form submission , user will take longer to submit
2. Track if mouse is moving for the first ie X seconds  , or if TAB key is pressed for users that don't use mouse.
3. Have a CSS hidden input field , and if it is populated and #1 or #2 returns ALARM than it is a bot 
   Combining 3 of those will get out  99% of bots.

Comment: What code would be used in your 2nd suggestion? Thanks.